# Why does my WiFi Network have a huge Subnet mask?

Tags: ip, subnet, ipconfig

I'm currently learning about IP and Routers, and have recently learned about Subnet Masks and their purposes. When I checked my own IPs (with `ipconfig`), I noticed an oddity:

My Ethernet Subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`, which I suppose is rather normal (although it leaves space for surprisingly many devices), but much more concerning is my Wireless LAN Subnet Mask, standing at `255.255.0.0`, which would be a ridiculous amount of possible devices in my network - which is just a FritzBox in my family home.

Is there any explanation to the size of this Subnet Mask, could it may be that I am misunderstanding the concept of Subnet Masks with WiFi or is this something I should change?

Any information is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: A netmask is a 32-bit binary mask used to divide an IP address into subnets and specify the network's available hosts.   https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/What_is_a_Netmask%3F

Comment: You certainly should feel free to change the network to be whatever you feel comfortable with.  Certain networks are reserved for your private use.  Most commonly, home networks start at 192.168.X.0 and run to 192.168.X.255.  In this case, the netmask would be 255.255.255.0.  Commonly the network can be expressed as 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 or 192.168.0.0/24

Comment: zkilnbqi indeed yes well said, the network is simply what one is *comfortable with* to suite their personal needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so 255.255.0.0 is the maximum amount of devices that can be used so probably the first two octets of all devices must be the same on the network for it to configuire itself as this. Alas your network does not believe itself to be running at full capacity but believes it has the ability to run at full capacity which is true right? (hopefully as it is new) Therefore you certainly have a set up calibration problem which is no worry and really an unnecessary issue that really at the end of the day has no problem unless you wanted to run some thing of the sort of  a mass AI learning system of independent integrated workstations on your home LAN (which again, i wouldnt expect)

A bit of extra clarification (perhaps unnecessary)but because you asked you asked for as much information :) ... the AI would only be a problem because it would always want to reach the max device number *you have allocated* when running and incrementing learning. The AI always overspills the max you have set but of course as it is set as the largest possible max on your system (at 255) it has *no overspill capabilities* at all and would cause a queue.

Comment: Thanks, so should/can I assume that it is in fact not normal that I have this big of a Subnet Mask and that it might be due to a misconfiguration in my router? I'll look into that when I have time, and see what the router itself has to say :)

Comment: *should/can I assume that it is in fact not normal* - that is a hard question i must say as most do not even consider to review their subnet mask and thus perhaps many people have the same data as you without looking. what i would say however is if you are looking to expand or really stress your system, perhaps look to resolving the issue, otherwise, it shouldn't do harm and is just a little quirk. - hope that helps :)

Comment: Funnily enough, I re-checked today to find a subnet mask of `255.255.255.0` - so the issue seemingly resolved itself. Very odd, though.

Comment: Yes as zkilnbqi said yesterday it really doent matter and your network probably (just surmising) had a feature  (that placed it at max reading in the first place) back down to normal